# When is the "displayName" in a Google Calendar Event included and when it is not?

Tags: google-calendar-api, displayname-attribute

I have a Google Calendar that I share with a group of people. I am using the Google Calendar APis to read the events in this calendar. Now, the "displayName" of the attendees to an event is sometimes available and sometimes not. So my question is, when is the"displayName" available? 
THe Google Calendar API says that the "displayName"is optional, but doesn't say how this applies when someone uses the Google Calendar application to add his email to the list .

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this only applies to Google-related email addresses (either GMail or other accounts that have been assigned to a GMail account), whereby the API retrieves the name of the Google user associated with the email address.

Also, even though it is editable in the API, any changes made to the displayName are ignored when the event is updated.

Edit: you can manually set the displayName property, but only when adding the attendee for the first time. It cannot be changed once the attendee has been added, which is rather inconvenient.